# Python Selenium can't find element in ellipse dropdown

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can anyone explain to me why this bit of code works perfectly fine when script is run in the foreground but fails when it is run in the background?

In short, the objective is to hover over a table in power BI so that the ellipse appears, then click on the ellipse and the export data button in the dropdown menu

[image]

The below code works perfectly when I run the script in python/spyder. The problem is when I schedule the script using task scheduler and select the 'Run whether user is logged on or not' option (Which forces it to run in the background), it fails when trying to click the export data button. Everything works fine when I select the 'Run only when user is logged on' option (Runs in the foreground).

[image]

```
time.sleep(20)
xpath='/html/body/div[1]/root/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/div[1]/div/report/exploration-container/div/div/docking-container/div/div/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container[8]/transform/div/div[2]/div/visual-modern/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[17]/div'
elem = driver.find_element("xpath",xpath)
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem)
hover.perform()

time.sleep(5)
xpath='//*[@id="pvExplorationHost"]/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container[8]/transform/div/visual-container-header/div/div/div/visual-container-options-menu/visual-header-item-container/div/button'
#click_item(xpath)
#SubmitXpath="//input[@id='idSIButton9']"
Submit = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,xpath)))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Submit)

time.sleep(5)   
xpath='/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/ng-component/pbi-menu/button[3]'
Submit = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,xpath)))
#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Submit)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Submit)
#click_item(xpath)
```

**Sidenote I am using Chromedriver.**

Please let me know if you require more information. I didn't want to make the post too long.